# Android Studio doesn't find JDK

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm using windows 10 here , I've created the system variable JAVA_HOME with the correct path to the JDK folder ( not the JRE ) like this :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_77
```

I've tried to add another user variable too with the same path and the JAVA_HOME but it doesn't seem to work , any idea what it could be ?

Comment: The current version of Studio is 2.0. Do you mean 1.0? If so, just upgrade it and retry. Should this be needed pick your SDK using Studio's built-in configuration features provided it starts. Not sure Studio 1 was supporting Java 8 btw.

Comment: Hm exactly , i downloaded it from their website and it was the 1.0 instead of the 2.0 , i'll try and see what happens

Comment: Well , i press to instal the Android Studio 2.0 and it installs me the 1.0 .... how can i upgrade it then ?